# Making the SearchBar retrieve accurate data in swift

Tags: swift, search, google-cloud-firestore

So far Ive gotten my searchbar to work with my firebase Firestore App, but for some reason my searchbar is not retrieving data accurately. Because, no matter what text I type in the search bar, the tableview presents the same item as my search results.

Im using Cloud Firestore as my database, but I don't think that that's the issue for why my search is posting the same item as the search result.

```
extension ProductListController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
   func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
       return 1
   }
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

       if searchBar.text != "" {
           return self.productInventory.count
       }
       return productSetup.count
   }

   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
       guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ProductListCell") as?
       ProductListCell else { return UITableViewCell() }

       //search not empty
       if searchBar.text != "" {
           cell.configure(withProduct: productInventory[indexPath.row])
       }

       cell.configure(withProduct: productSetup[indexPath.row])

       return cell
   }
}
```

---

I've looked through multiple questions on stack and seems like the answers I'm getting are not much help. Hopefully someone here can help me figure this out and solve my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think problem is in cellForRowAt:- Try This

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

```
      guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ProductListCell") as?
    ProductListCell else { return UITableViewCell() }

      //search not empty
      if searchBar.text != "" {
          cell.configure(withProduct: productInventory[indexPath.row])
      }else{

         cell.configure(withProduct: productSetup[indexPath.row])
      }



      return cell
  }
```

Comment: you just gave me the exact code I have written out for cellForRowAt @Neeraj

Comment: No your code don't have else block just check @evelynphillips

Comment: have you looked for the same? is this solved your problem?